# Check if the value of an object property is an object

Tags: javascript

```js
    const opb = {
    'e' : 1,
     '3' : 2,
      '4' : {'ee':12}
    }
    
    Object.entries(opb).forEach(el => {console.log(el[1] !== typeof 'object' , typeof el[1])})
```

Hello im building a check that checks if the first value of an object property is another object.

I am doing this as follow:

```js
    const opb = {
    'e' : 1,
     '3' : 2,
      '4' : {'ee':12}
    }
    
    Object.entries(opb).forEach(el => {console.log(el[1] !== typeof 'object' , el[1])})
```

Somehow everything returns true, eventho one should be an object (false).

Comment: _"The `typeof` operator returns a string indicating **the type of the unevaluated operand**"_

Comment: Just as a side note, none of the single quotes you have in your object literals are necessary. Property names don't need to be in quotes unless they're A) Not valid identifier names, and B) Not valid numeric literals. Your property names are all either valid identifier names or numeric literals.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Isn't `-1` a valid numeric literal? You can't do `{-1: 0}`. Is it a UnaryExpression?

Comment: @nickzoum - Very good point to raise! No, `-1` isn't a numeric literal, it's the negation operator and the numeric literal `1`. (Yes, really. :-D) It doesn't work because the negation operator isn't allowed there. [Here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-LiteralPropertyName) are the valid productions for property names, the third of which is [NumericLiteral](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-NumericLiteral). If you kick around NumericLiteral, you'll find that `-` doesn't appear. :-) Just one of those funny things about JavaScript (and Java) syntax. I should have mentioned it above.

Comment: @nickzoum - (Weird as this is in JavaScript, it's even weirder in Java. It means that you can't have a decimal numeric literal that defines a negative int, long, or short, but you *can* have a hex, octal, or binary numerc literal that defines one.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Wow

Comment: @nickzoum - Weird, eh? 0xFFFFFFFF is a Java numeric int literal for -1. But you can't write it in decimal, you have to use the negation operator. ANYway.... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `typeof el[1] !== 'object'`.

```js
const opb = {
    'e' : 1,
     '3' : 2,
      '4' : {'ee':12}
    }
    
    Object.entries(opb).forEach(el => {console.log(typeof el[1] !== 'object' , el[1])})
```